# new Date showing tomorrows date instead of today

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, google-sheets-api

I have setup a google web app that enters data into a google spreadsheet and timestamps it using the new date function. The issue i'm having is between midnight and 1am the date is pushed forward to the next day. for example if im entering data in at 12/03/2019 00:45am, the date that appears in the google spreadsheet is the 13/03/2019 00:45am. I use var timestamp to display the date and time and var date to show just the date. the weird thing is, var date gets the date correct where timestamp does not, even though they are both used at the exact same time. I only seem to have this issue between midnight and 1am Any help that anyone could provide is greatly appreciated.

```
var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+10", "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss");

var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+10", "dd-MM-yy");
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                var rowValues = [
                    [state, owner, type, fleet, rego, date, date, site, User, timestamp, comment]
                ]
                var lar = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
                var lar1 = archive.getLastRow() + 1
                var lar2 = STate.getLastRow() + 1
                var request = {
                    'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
                    'data': [{
                            'range': 'National Master!A' + lar + ':K' + lar + '',
                            'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
                            'values': rowValues
                        },
                        {
                            'range': 'Archive!A' + lar1 + ':K' + lar1 + '',
                            'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
                            'values': rowValues
                        },
                        {
                            'range': '' + state + '!A' + lar2 + ':K' + lar2 + '',
                            'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
                            'values': rowValues
                        }
                    ]
                };
                var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, "sheet id here");
```

Comment: Replace the hardcoded time zone definition (GMT+10) with Session.getScriptTimeZone() to avoid issues related to daylight savings.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the letter representing hours from `k` to `H` in

```
var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+10", "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss");
```

If you look at the [ref docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you'll see that

- `k` is defined as "Hour in day (1-24)"
- while `H` is defined as "Hour in day (0-23)"

I tested this with the following script:

```
function dateCheck() {
  var d = new Date( 2019, 7, 17, 0, 45, 0 );
  var timestampK = Utilities.formatDate(d, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss");
  var timestampH = Utilities.formatDate(d, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  Logger.log(timestampK);
  Logger.log(timestampH);
}
```

I got the following output:

> 17/08/2019 **24**:45:00
>
> 17/08/2019 **00**:45:00

`k` at `0` is pushing the date to tomorrow by adding 24 hours.